# How to execute threads every min correctly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.timers.timer

This question is in two parts.
I have a console application that gets info from several servers and saves this info to a DB. In order to enabel that this executes simultaniously i have used threads. I am trying to make this execution automatic every minute.

Searching stackoverflow i found that this could work:

```
   var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {
            var models = ServerHandler.GetServerModels();

            foreach (var m in models)
            {
                ServerHandler.MakeThreads(m);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Running...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'X' to exit or close the window, i : " + i);

            i++;


        }, null, 0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).Seconds);
```

However this is not working as anticipated, it only executes once. If i change to for example this:

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5).Seconds
```

Or:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Seconds
```

Then it works. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Second part of this question:**

When this actually works as I showed above something else happens. 
The process runs continuously and after 474 threads it crashes and says that the system is out of memory.

I tried using thread sleep for this but when i do that it stops executing after it has runed once.

Including this if it might help:

```
public static void MakeThreads(ServerModel model)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => SaveServerInfo(model));
    thread.Start();
    //Thread.Sleep(1);
    //thread.Join();

}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: 'TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).Seconds' returns 0.  You want 'TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalSeconds' which returns 60.

Comment: I would use the `TimeSpan` overload. _https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch(v=vs.110).aspx_

Comment: How about `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60).Seconds` ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first problem using the .Seconds will only return the seconds value, but you are defining the minutes value as .5, so seconds will always be zero.

If you want to return the seconds you need to use TotalSeconds

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5).TotalSeconds
```

and in the timespan you are using you are supposed to define the milliseconds. So you're getting a huge number of threads because its running every 30 millseconds instead of every 30000 milliseconds.

So use

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.5).TotalMilliseconds
```

or what i always find easier

```
(int)(1000 * 60 * 0.5)  // Then you just replace the 0.5 with the number of seconds.
```

Comment: tried that, it runs every second till I have 475 threads and then it crashes

Comment: So the execution takes longer than the interval. Thats a performance problem. You should try something else...

Comment: @Ra3IDeN See the second part of my answer which i updated.

Comment: Alright I think this is actually what I am looking for. Although I would appreciate a simple clarification. I copied the second part of your answer and figured that the execution would occur every 30 seconds. I have had the application running for 3 minutes now and it has only executed once.
my code currently:
(int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000 * 60 * 0.5).TotalSeconds)

Comment: @CathalMF To be honest, I'm not sure why you even bother to convert a `TimeSpan` to an integer while the `Timer` class already accepts a `TimeSpan`. If you just use it as-is, there's no possible confusion.

Comment: If you're creating 475 threads, perhaps you should think about a completely different design pattern, because that's INSANE.

Comment: @Bauss Yeap. He might be creating that many threads because new threads spawn before the old ones are finished, or just because he doesn't use proper pooling. `Parallel.ForEach` fixes both issues.

Comment: It's pointless to really create more threads than you have cores since your cpu is not really able to process more than that at once anyway. Of course there's a difference between hardware threads and managed threads, but overall the managed threads will still somehow operate that way. Just like when you have a server that can run 10k clients connected at once, you don't have 10k threads to make sure they all get handled "asynchronously". You typically can even do it on a single thread or maybe a little amount.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a timer does exactly what it's supposed to do: run your code every 0.5 seconds. :) An in your case, that's a problem...

(Please check for syntax errors etc, I'm writing this in notepad)

**Long solution**

Your problem seems to be that you don't control your threads. Here's how I'd solve it: (This long solution shows how it more or less works)

```
while (true)
{    
    // we want to run it again in 0.5 seconds.
    DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(0.5); 

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[models.Count];
    for (int i=0; i<models.Count; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread((a) => SaveServerInfo((ServerModel)a));
        threads[i].Start(models[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<models.Count; ++i)
    {
        threads[i].Join();
    }

    DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (current < start)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(start.Subtract(current));
    }

}
```

**Short solution**

However, this might give you issues as well: you might spawn too many threads. This can be solved with a mechanism called thread pooling. As it turns out, there's a simple way to solve this:

```
static void DoStuff(string s)
{
    // change to a value > 0.5 as well to ensure everything works
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1)); 
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static void Handle(List<string> models)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // we want to run it again in 0.5 seconds.
        DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(0.5);

        Parallel.ForEach(models, (a) => DoStuff(a));
        DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (current < start)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(start.Subtract(current));
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> models = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        models.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    Handle(models);

}
```

Comment: this did not work. First soloution gave me an index out of range exception as soon as i did not run it in the debugger. Second solution only ran the threads once and then stopped.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN I did forget a thread start in the first example; that's fixed now. The second solution works as-is. If you get an index out of range exception, you're changing the collection in a thread -- **that's not allowed in any case, you're creating a race condition!** As for you claims that it doesn't work, I've just created a minimum test case and it works just fine; feel free to check for yourself.